# How can I print elements from an imported text file in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface

Okay, so as my school assignment I have been told to import a txt file and store it inside a list, I have done this correctly, and the next step is to print the items in a 3x3 grid. I have come up with a solution however it doesn't seem to be working.. Here is my code:

```
import time
import random

words = open("Words.txt","r")
WordList = []
for lines in words:

WordList.append(lines)
WordList=[line.rstrip('\n')for line in WordList]

print(WordList(0,2))
```

What my solution was is that I would print out 3 at a time from the list, so I would print position 0, 1 and 2. Then I would print 3, 4 and 5 then I would print 6, 7 and 8 and I would have my solution.

Comment: May I also add that the problem is when I use:

    print(WordList(0,2)) <-- This doesn't work

Comment: The proper way to slice a list is `my_list[start:stop:step]`, with `start` being inclusive and `stop` is exclusive. So your example should be: `word_list[:3]`. you can leave out the 0 as it is implied by passing a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the lines into a list and then print the list while adding a new line every third print, don't append the lines to the WordList.

```
words= words.rstrip('\n')
WordList = words.split(" ")

count = 0
for word in WordList:
    if count % 3 == 0:
        print("\n")
    print (word)
    count++
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is simple:

```
print(WordList[0:3])
print(WordList[3:6])
print(WordList[6:9])
```